# Shell Script - Block Sequence check and add missing block

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to scan blocks lets say from 1 to 10.

lets say

**(3,1,4,8,2,7,9,10)**

min block = 1 , max block = 10

expected sequence = 1 to 10

***missing blocks= 5,6***

I need a shell script that is going to pick up the missing block in the range and add them to create a new set. Sorting is not needed though

Best Regards,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to Bitcoin.

Comment: @PieterWuille, I just modified my question. I am trying to scan the bitcoin blockchain and filter out transactions based upon the addresses that belong to me. I am missing some blocks.

Comment: This seems to be a question about shell-scripting. You can probably ask on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) about how to find missing numbers in an unordered list. In any case, you should post the shell-script you have written so far, or a simplified version, and explain how it's output differs from what you need.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick That is fine ! Here is another question that was answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727809/finding-the-missing-values-in-a-range-using-any-scripting-language-perl-pytho ? What is the bias for ? I can still find a solution to the problem but the responses don't encourage to post questions anymore

Comment: You are more likely to find an answer about subject X on a site that has large numbers of visitors with experience in subject X than you will on a site about subject A which only occasionally involves the use of something from subject X. It is an attempt to be helpful